# How to set how long a user can be locked out after several failed attempt?

Tags: php, mysql, database, loops, session

I want to lock out a particular user from trying to login after multiple failed attempts for 10 min. The aim is to user pNumber as the locking criteria not the IP address because the IP address is used by multiple users.

When I perform a select based on ip, the code is able to check if the user has entered a wrong pNumber and password, and if that is true. It prints the error indicating the first attempt was wrong and at the same time it stores the failed attempt in a db_table. So when the total failed attempt is >= 3, it locks.

This is not what I want, because I want it to lock for a specific amount of time and it should lock based on users pNumber and not IP address. The IP address is share by many users.

```
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
    header("Location: home.php");
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{

    //check login attempts 
    $userIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $attempt_id = NULL;
    $when = date('m/d/Y h:i:s', time());
    $aptSql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(ip) AS failed_log FROM attempts WHERE pNumber='$pNumber'");
    $row_count = mysql_fetch_assoc($aptSql);
    $failed_attempt = $row_count['failed_log']; 
    $aptSql = mysql_free_result();
    ?>

        <script>alert('<?php echo $failed_attempt;?>');</script>
    <?php
    if($failed_attempt >= 3)
    {
        $time = new Datetime();
        ?>          
            <script>alert('Sorry, you have exceeded numbers of attempts allowed. Please see your department manager');</script> 
        <?php


    }
    else
    {

        //Users login details 
        $pNumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pNumber']);
        $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

        //check the details entered by user     
        $res=mysql_query("SELECT users.*, employees.* FROM users NATURAL JOIN employees WHERE users.pNumber='$pNumber'");
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);

        if($row['password']==md5($upass))
        {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
            header("Location: home.php");
        }
        else
        {
            //Insert login attempts to table



            $insertSql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `employees`.`attempts` (`id`, `ip`, `when`, `pNumber`) VALUES ('$attempt_id', '$userIP', '$when', '$pNumber')");

            //result 
            if($insertSql != false)
            {

                    ?>
                        <script>alert('You entered an invalid username or password, your attempt has been stored.');</script>
                    <?php

            }

            else
            {
                ?>
                    <script>alert('Error Inserting your details. Please, see your department manager');</script>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="Lee & Micheal" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../favicon.ico">

    <title>Employee Time Stamp System</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="signin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- debug and js -->
    <script src="../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>

    <div class="container">

        <tr>
        <td><center><h1>EMPLOYEE LOGIN</h1></center><br></td>
        </tr>
         <form method="post" class="form-signin" ><br>
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">LOGIN</h2>
            <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Personal ID</label>
            <input type="text" name="pNumber" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Personal ID" required autofocus>
            <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="pass" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
              </label>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="btn-login">Login in</button>
         </form>


    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Should i change these code too?

```
$pNumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pNumber']);
$upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
```

To:

```
$pNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['pNumber']);
$upass = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
```

This is how the code look like now

```
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
    header("Location: home.php");
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{

    //check login attempts 
    $userIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $attempt_id = NULL;
    $when = date('m/d/Y h:i:s', time());
    $aptSql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(ip) AS failed_log FROM attempts WHERE pNumber='$pNumber'");
    row_count = mysqli_fetch_assoc($aptSql);
    $failed_attempt = $row_count['failed_log']; 

    $aptSql = mysqli_free_result();
    ?>

        <script>alert('<?php echo $failed_attempt;?>');</script>
    <?php
    if($failed_attempt >= 3)
    {
        $time = new Datetime();
        ?>          
            <script>alert('Sorry, you have exceeded numbers of attempts allowed. Please see your department manager');</script> 
        <?php


    }
    else
    {

        //Users login details 
        $pNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['pNumber']);
        $upass = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

        //check the details entered by user     
        $res=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT users.*, employees.* FROM users NATURAL JOIN employees WHERE users.pNumber='$pNumber'");
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);

        if($row['password']==phpass($upass))
        {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
            header("Location: home.php");
        }
        else
        {
            //Insert login attempts to table



            $insertSql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `employees`.`attempts` (`id`, `ip`, `when`, `pNumber`) VALUES ('$attempt_id', '$userIP', '$when', '$pNumber')");

            //result 
            if($insertSql != false)
            {

                    ?>
                        <script>alert('You entered an invalid username or password, your attempt has been stored.');</script>
                    <?php

            }

            else
            {
                ?>
                    <script>alert('Error Inserting your details. Please, see your department manager');</script>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="Lee & Micheal" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../favicon.ico">

    <title>Employee Time Stamp System</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="signin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- debug and js -->
    <script src="../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>

    <div class="container">

        <tr>
        <td><center><h1>EMPLOYEE LOGIN</h1></center><br></td>
        </tr>
         <form method="post" class="form-signin" ><br>
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">LOGIN</h2>
            <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Personal ID</label>
            <input type="text" name="pNumber" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Personal ID" required autofocus>
            <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="pass" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
              </label>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="btn-login">Login in</button>
         </form>


    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

What is the problem now

```
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
    header("Location: home.php");
}else

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{

    //check login attempts 
    $pNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['pNumber']);
    $upass = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

    $userIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $attempt_id = NULL;
    $when = date('m/d/Y h:i:s', time());

    $aptSql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(ip) AS failed_log FROM attempts WHERE pNumber='$pNumber'");

    $row_count = mysqli_fetch_assoc($aptSql);
    $failed_attempt = $row_count['failed_log'];
    $lastlocked = date('m/d/Y h:i:s', time());

    $query = mysqli_query ($con, "SELECT id, pNumber, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(lastlocked) as lockDatetimestamp ROM manage_users HERE (id = $attempt_id) and (lastlocked IS NOT NULL) and
    (lastlocked <= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE))");
    $new_row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $aptSql = mysqli_free_result();
    ?>

        <script>alert('<?php echo $failed_attempt;?>');</script>
    <?php
    if($failed_attempt >= 3)
    {

        ?>          
            <script>alert('Sorry, you have exceeded numbers of attempts allowed. Please see your department manager');</script> 
        <?php


    }   
    else
    {

        //Users login details 


        //check the details entered by user     
        $res=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT users.*, employees.* FROM users NATURAL JOIN employees WHERE users.pNumber='$pNumber'");
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);

        if($row['password']==phpass($upass))
        {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
            header("Location: home.php");
        }
        else
        {
            //Insert login attempts to table        
            $insertSql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `employees`.`attempts` (`id`, `ip`, `when`, `pNumber`, `lastlocked`) VALUES ('$attempt_id', '$userIP', '$when', '$pNumber', '$lastlocked')");

            //result 
            if($insertSql != false)
            {

                    ?>
                        <script>alert('You entered an invalid username or password, your attempt has been stored.');</script>
                    <?php

            }

            else
            {
                ?>
                    <script>alert('Error Inserting your details. Please, see your department manager');</script>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }



}
```

there is a problem with this code an idel

```
$row_count = mysqli_fetch_assoc($aptSql);
    $failed_attempt = $row_count['failed_log'];
    $lastlocked = date('m/d/Y h:i:s', time());

    $query = mysqli_query ($con, "SELECT id, pNumber, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(lastlocked) as lockDatetimestamp ROM manage_users HERE (id = $attempt_id) and (lastlocked IS NOT NULL) and
    (lastlocked <= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE))");
    $new_row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $lockedtime = $mysqli_fetch_array['lockDatetimestamp'];
    $query=mysqli_free_result();
    $aptSql = mysqli_free_result();
```

Some updates has been made. First I had to revert to the old mysql statement to first ensure that the code does what it has to do. When the problem gets solved I will change it back to mysqli statement.

The problem now after lock down of attempts that are more than >=3. Its difficult comparing the MAX(lastlocked) with the current time which is 30 minutes over to unlock the login form again. So my problem is how to go do this and should I use switch loop and secondly the if($failed_attempt >= 3) is blocking all user, which is not what I want.

```
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
    header("Location: home.php");
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
    //prevents SQL injecions
    $pNumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pNumber']);
    $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);  


    //used for failed attempts 
    $userIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $attempt_id = NULL;
    $aptSql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(pNumber) AS failed_log FROM attempts WHERE ip='$userIP'");
    $row_count = mysql_fetch_assoc($aptSql);
    $failed_attempt = $row_count['failed_log'];     

    $lastlocked = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(lastlocked) FROM attempts WHERE pNumber='$pNumber'");
    $yeah = mysql_fetch_array($lastlocked);
    if($failed_attempt >= 3)
    {

        ?>          
            <script>alert('Sorry, you have exceeded numbers of attempts allowed. Please see your department manager');</script> 
        <?php


    }
    elseif(strtotime($lastlocked) < time())
    {
        ?>
            <script>alert('<?php echo $lastlocked['lastlocked'];?>');</script>


                    <?php

    }
    else
    {
        $res=mysql_query("SELECT users.*, employees.* FROM users NATURAL JOIN employees WHERE users.pNumber='$pNumber'");
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);

            if($row['password']==md5($upass))
        {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
            header("Location: home.php");
        }
        else
        {
            //Insert login attempts to table            
            $insertSql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `employees`.`attempts` (`id`, `ip`, `pNumber`) VALUES ('$attempt_id', '$userIP', '$pNumber')");

            //result 
            if($insertSql != false)
            {               
                ?>
                    <script>
                        alert('You entered an invalid username or password, your attempt has been stored.');
                    </script>
                <?php

            }

            else
            {
                ?>
                    <script>
                        alert('Error Inserting your details. Please, see your department manager');
                    </script>
                <?php
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Finally, solve the problem and the contribution I got from here helped me.
Below is the working code for anyone having the same problem.

```
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
    header("Location: home.php");
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
    //prevents SQL injecions
    $pNumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pNumber']);
    $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);  


    //used for failed attempts 
    $userIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $attempt_id = NULL;
    $aptSql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(pNumber) AS failed_log FROM attempts WHERE pNumber='$pNumber'");
    $row_count = mysql_fetch_assoc($aptSql);
    $failed_attempt = $row_count['failed_log'];     

    $locked_time = mysql_query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(), DATE_ADD(lastlocked, INTERVAL 2 MINUTE) AS cheknow FROM `attempts` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
    $show_row_res = mysql_fetch_array($locked_time);
    $convert_time= strtotime($show_row_res['cheknow']);
    $current_time = time();


    ?>      

            <script>alert('The time now is : <?php echo $current_time; ?>') </script> 
            <script>alert('The converted time : <?php echo $convert_time['cheknow']; ?>') </script> 
    <?php

    //check attempts and lock out user not ip address

    if($failed_attempt >= 3 and $convert_time > $current_time)
    {

        ?>          
            <script>alert('Sorry, you have exceeded numbers of attempts allowed. Please see your department manager');</script> 
        <?php


    }
    else
    {
        $res=mysql_query("SELECT users.*, employees.* FROM users NATURAL JOIN employees WHERE users.pNumber='$pNumber'");
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);

            if($row['password']==md5($upass))
        {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
            header("Location: home.php");
        }
        else
        {
            //Insert login attempts to table            
            $insertSql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `employees`.`attempts` (`id`, `ip`, `pNumber`) VALUES ('$attempt_id', '$userIP', '$pNumber')");

            //result 
            if($insertSql != false)
            {               
                ?>
                    <script>
                        alert('You entered an invalid username or password, your attempt has been stored.');
                    </script>
                <?php

            }

            else
            {
                ?>
                    <script>
                        alert('Error Inserting your details. Please, see your department manager');
                    </script>
                <?php
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use `mysqli` since `mysql` is depreciated and then use `mysqli_num_rows`

Comment: You are hashing passwords (this is good) but you are using MD5 (this is bad) and you are not salting them per user (this is bad). PHP comes with a `hash_password()` function that does all of this stuff for you very easily.

Comment: Is the "pNumber" essentially a username? If so, remember that users can be locked out by malicious parties wanting to lock your users account - their job is to discover pNumbers and then get the passwords repeatedly wrong. Affected users won't be able to log in.

Comment: its a school project and I am behind schedule

Comment: any idea how I can solve the problem?

Comment: In your first query you are referencing `$pNumber`, which does not exist yet. I'd fix that first.

Comment: After your edit, you are still accessing variables that do not exist.

Comment: Alright but I have a connection issue, I still get 500 internal server error

Comment: A "500 error" means there is an issue that is explained in your logs, and not on the screen. Check your Apache logs - it's probably a PHP error.

Comment: I got the error handled but still not working

Comment: Dose any one have an idea why the program is not working. I think, there is issue with the $querry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all. Please use `mysqli` or `PDO` as `mysql` is depreciated and will be removed in PHP7. In the code I have suggested, it uses the `mysqli` which requires the connection variable, in this case defined as $con.
In case you haven't already, the connection is defined as such:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("my_ip", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
```

From what I can tell in your `$aptSql` query it has `COUNT(ip)`. I don't know exactly what is happening here but I would suggest one of the following.

```
$aptSql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS failed_log FROM attempts WHERE pNumber='$pNumber'");
$row_count = mysqli_fetch_assoc($aptSql);
$failed_attempt = $row_count['failed_log']; 
$aptSql = mysqli_free_result();
```

Or:

```
$aptSql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM attempts WHERE pNumber='$pNumber'");
$failed_attempt = mysqli_num_rows($aptSql);
$aptSql = mysqli_free_result();
```

The second line in this option may also be: (I am doing this from memory and do not have a testing environment currently)

```
$failed_attempt = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_fetch_assoc($aptSql));
```

To lock for a certain time, add the time the account was locked to the user data base under something along the lines of `lastlocked` and compare it to the current time when logging in to check if 10 minutes has passed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok there are two things I have to suggest.

**Firstly**: After the user is locked out and the time is recorded, to prevent the user from being locked out due to this line: `if($failed_attempt >= 3)` **Reset the failed attempt count for that user**
When checking if the user is blocked out, check it against the time, not the number of failed attempts. Use the failed attempts to initiate the lock. That way after the lock has expired the user wont be locked out from the failed attempts.

**Secondly**: When checking if the user is locked out (by comparing the time), you can compare the time recorded to the current time in a way such as:

```
if (time() - $recordedtime) < 1800) { /* 1800 seconds is 30 minutes */
    /* user is locked out */
}
```

This checks if 1800 seconds (30 minutes) has passed since the recorded time.

**Note: As this doesn't check date there may be complications if the user tries logging in the next day. Therefor I suggest you remove the recorded time stored after the lock has expired.**